# SWRevealViewController with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

[app configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhbRk.png)

This is My configuration with SWRevealViewController, UITabController, four ViewControllers connected to the UITabBarController via UINavgationController. The tab bar controller is set as sw_front and the left top table view is set as the sw_rear. The code I used for the sw_rear is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! MainTabBarController

    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "superDeals") as! SuperDealsViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
        navigationController.setViewControllers([destinationVC], animated: true)
        tabBarController.setViewControllers([navigationController], animated: true)
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
        self.revealViewController().setFront(tabBarController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "allDeals") as! AllDealsViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
        navigationController.setViewControllers([destinationVC], animated: true)
        tabBarController.setViewControllers([navigationController], animated: true)
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
        self.revealViewController().setFront(tabBarController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
    }else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "coupon") as! CouponsViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
        navigationController.setViewControllers([destinationVC], animated: true)
        tabBarController.setViewControllers([navigationController], animated: true)
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
        self.revealViewController().setFront(tabBarController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
    }else if(indexPath.row == 3){
        let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "forum") as! ForumViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
        navigationController.setViewControllers([destinationVC], animated: true)
        tabBarController.setViewControllers([navigationController], animated: true)
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3
        self.revealViewController().setFront(tabBarController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
    }else if(indexPath.row == 4){
        let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "stores") as! StoresViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
        navigationController.setViewControllers([destinationVC], animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
    }else if(indexPath.row == 5){
        let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "categories") as! categoriesViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
        navigationController.setViewControllers([destinationVC], animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
    }else if(indexPath.row == 6){
        if(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "token") == nil){
            let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! LoginViewController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
            navigationController.setViewControllers([destinationVC], animated: true)
            self.revealViewController().setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
            self.revealViewController().bounceBackOnLeftOverdraw = true
            self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
        }else{
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "token")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Log out successful.", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: {
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "base") as! SWRevealViewController
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working and navigating to the viewcontrollers properly, but the tab bar items are not showing. I have attached the images for clarification. Can someone please help? I want to show the tabbar in each of my viewcontrollers..

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUQSG.png)

[How it is currently showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARoM1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only select the index

```
let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! MainTabBarController

if(indexPath.row == 0){

    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
    self.revealViewController().setFront(tabBarController, animated: true)
    self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Issue resolved. Was thinking way too more than needed.